# Query Syntax in mongodb for "between" - i am using java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mongodb

i want to retrieve data which their "price" field is between a certain max and min , i am using syntax below in java but it seems that it is not working .

>

```
 BasicDBObject numeralQ;                                                                
List<DBObject> clauses = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
.
.
.
.
numeralQ.put(datafield,new BasicDBObject("$gt", min).append("$lt", max));
clauses.add(numeralQ);  
.
.//i also have many other conditions that i want to "OR" them with this condition
.
BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();

for (DBObject clause : clauses)
    or.add(clause);

DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", or);
DBCursor cur = coll.find(query);

while (cur.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cur.next());

}
```

can you see what am i doing wrong?

--EDIT

```
printing the `query.toString();` results in this string :
```

`{ "$or" : [ { "Price" : { "$gt" : "2" , "$lt" : "1250"}}]}`

Comment: Can you show the output of query.toString() before you call find, or show the same query in the mongo javascript shell?

Comment: { "$or" : [ { "Price" : { "$gt" : "2" , "$lt" : "1250"}}]}

Comment: any one who has down voted : please give me and public a REASON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to compare the price as numbers, not strings.  So you want to end up with a condition object that looks like:

```
{ "Price": {"$gt": 2, "$lt": 1250 } }
```

Comment: yipppppiii , i changed to integer and it works now, the only problem is that when i am using $or, if the compare fields remain empty, the query will return all data.

Comment: You are using $or when you should be using $and.

Think about it - if price is greater than 10 or price is less than 20 that's every possible price in the universe.  Change it back to {"Price": {$gt":2, "$lt":1250} (comma is an implicit "and") and you'll get the right data.

Comment: nop, the price compare is working fine, i am using or for other queries, for example if price is gt:10 and lt:40 , OR the "title" field contains "this is free"